# How can I pass an entire string of data from an html element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to pass data from an HTML element and serialize it. At the moment I can do it by naming each individual attribute in the HTML tag. But It seems verbose and complicated.

```
<a data-type="2" data-post="101" data-parent="100">Up</a>
var myData = $(this).data("type")+$(this).data("parent")+$(this).data("post")
```

Can I pass all of the data with a single call instead of naming each individual attribute? For example:

```
var myData = $(this).data(all the attributes go here in some sort of string/serialized string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: This requires jQuery 1.4.4

You could do:

```
var myData = $(this).data();
var str = '';
for(var i in myData) {
    if(myData.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        str += myData[i];
    }
}
// generates "2101100"
```

But note that `data()` might return more then just the HTML data attributes.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZwD9/)

Depending on how you want to serialize the data, JSON.stringify might also be ok for you (which generates a JSON string):

```
var myData = $(this).data();
var str = JSON.stringify(myData);
// generates: {"type":2,"post":101,"parent":100}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZwD9/1/)